# Spark 2.0 groupBy column and then get max(date) on a datetype column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.0 in Java.
I have a Dataset which look like this:

```
------+----+----+----+----------------+
    ID|col1|col2|col3|            date|
------+----+----+----+----------------+
981200| a  | q  | z  |      2010-12-30|
968800| s  | w  | x  |      2010-12-31|
966500| d  | e  | c  |      2010-11-02|
966500| f  | r  | v  |      2010-12-01|
981200| g  | t  | b  |      2010-12-03|
```

I wanto to groupBy ID and get only the row with the "last" date (the most recent one). The type of column "date" is **date**.

In my case the result would be

```
------+----------------+
    ID|       max(date)|
------+----------------+
981200|      2010-12-30|
968800|      2010-12-31|
966500|      2010-12-01|
```

I tried

```
    Dataset<Row> df = old_df.groupBy("ID").max("date");
```

but fails with error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
>       "date" is not a numeric column.
>       Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.;

Is there a way to get the max date (using type date) in Spark?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RelationalGroupedDataset.max` is for numeric values only.

You could try `agg()` with the accompanying `max` function. In Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
old_df.groupBy($"ID").agg(max("date"))
```

so in Java it should be:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
old_df.groupBy("ID").agg(max("date"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This workaround showed the result for me in Palantir (an environment for Scala) in PySpark:

```
def get_max_from_date(country_ref):
    return country_ref\
        .selectExpr("cast(date_format(from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') as decimal(8,0)) as c")\
        .agg(F.max('c').alias('max_c'))\
        .selectExpr("cast(max_c as varchar(8)) as max_c_string")\
        .select(F.to_date(F.col('max_c_string'), 'YYYYMMDD')).alias("max_from_date")
```

So:

- convert to string
- convert to integer
- get the maximum
- convert to string
- convert back to date

See also [PySpark groupby and max value selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889564/pyspark-groupby-and-max-value-selection)

Side note: Ah, remember how easy and quick it is in SQL! How immature Scala seems to be! Not diminishing all its Big Data capabilities in any way!